# error TS2307: Cannot find module 'react'

Tags: reactjs, typescript1.8

I am trying to create a component with typescript but I am getting the following error in the terminal yet I already installed `react` and `react-dom` using `npm`.

```
ERROR in ./main.tsx  error TS2307: Cannot find module 'react'.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oooh I see.. Try this

You also need to install the typescript definition files for react. You can do that using npm as shown below

```
npm install @types/react
```